How to join tables efficiently?
In Java, with JPA and EclipseLink. Lets say I have 3 tables: Supplier, Order and Customer
I want to get all customers that have an order by said supplier. Say suppliers and customers are not directly linked. They can only be linked by joining through orders:

An order can have one customer
A customer can have multiple orders
An order is also linked to a supplier
A supplier can have many orders
A order can have only 1 supplier

One way to do it:
In JPA once you setup your Model/Entity you can do
EntityManager.find(Supplier.class, 1)

This will return the supplier and its orders, from there we can get to the orders and get all the customers linked to that supplier. But this way fetches all the data, while we only want the Customers, nothing else, it puts strain on the DB and the client bandwith.
What is a better JPA, JPQL way to fetch only the Customers data that is linked to a supplier? I know that I can do a raw query but that kind of defeats the purpose of JPA.

JPQL also supports joins, e.g. something like SELECT c FROM Suppliers s JOIN s.orders o JOIN o.customers c WHERE s.id = 1 (or even the reverse would be possible). I'm pretty sure the criteria api will allow you to write something similar.

I see thanks could you give me a code example of how that would return a list of customers, what if I wanted both the customers and the orders

Assuming that you have defined a @ManyToOne relationship in Order to both Customer and Supplier, like this:
@Entity
@Table("order")
public class Order {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
   private Customer customer;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
   private Supplier supplier;
   
   ...
}

You could have a JPQL query like this:
List<Customer> customers = entityManager.createQuery("select distinct o.customer from Order o where o.supplier.id = :supplierId").getResultList();

If you wanted the order data too, you could get just the Orders as follows, and then stream them to get the customers:
List<Order> orders = entityManager.createQuery("select o from Order o where o.supplier.id = :supplierId").getResultList();

Map<Customer, List<Order>> customerOrders = orders.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomer));

//if you still need the customers on their own
Set<Customer> customers = customerOrders.keySet();


Hmm thanks, thats not entirely what I am looking for though, I also need the customers data.

If we would have gone the stupid way and done SELECT distinct o.customer FROM supplier s JOIN order o ON o.supplierid = s.id JOIN customer c ON c.id = o.customerid WHERE supplierid = :supplierd 
Is that possible in JPQL? How would it put it inside a list?

o.customer gives you the list of Customer objects, with all their data. The JPQL query is automatically translating to joins underneath the hood.

Added the java part that turns it into a list for you

Thanks that fully solves my problem. However just out of curiousity, what would the JPQL look like if I wanted both the customers data and orders data?

That would simply be select o from Order o where o.supplier.id = :supplierId. If the ManyToOne of the Customer has FetchType.EAGER the Customer object would be populated automatically. Don't always use EAGER though. For example if you have a @OneToMany from Supplier to Order and there are thousands of orders, using EAGER would retrieve all orders each time you get the supplier. I think by default its EAGER so make sure you set it to LAZY.

Added the java code to the answer to get the orders grouped by customer for a specific supplier.

Thankyou for showing the orders fetch but I actually meant in one query something like this: `Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c, o FROM Customer c JOIN c.orders o WHERE o.supplier.id = :supplierId");
query.setParameter("supplierId", supplierId);
// Execute the query and get the results
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();`
Is that a good way?

Returning an untyped Object[] is a bit messy in my opinion. I don't think you need to go that way for your problem, given that the relationship is very clean. The Order  already has the Customer populated, so can't see why you need to query it separately. All you need is to extract it from the Order if you need it separately.

Just curious if it was possible :P, so anyways doing it like that withouth an object/common interface/class list  isnt possible I presume? Best to always fetch one who has the other, in this case order?  So I should query the orders and then just use the .customer property of order :)

You can do joins of course as much as you like. I just think that in this case its cleaner and more typesafe, and the data will be there anyway inside the Order. If you want to use JPA through Spring Data JPA it also has Projections, where you can have your own object, for instance CustomerOrder that contains Customer and Order, both as constructor parameters, and you get List<CustomerOrder>, but in my opinion a bit useless, because Order has the Customer.

I see thanks a lot for the help I really appreciate it! Do you have any good guides on JPA or a book or something I can use to get better at it?

Haven't looked at any recently, but this one seems quite comprehensive: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/index.htm ... furthermore, you might want to use Spring Data JPA (instead of accessing the EntityManager) it abstracts you from a lot of boilerplate.
